# What Does Oracle in Multi-Armed Bandit Literatures?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, multiarmed-bandit, contextual-bandit

Often encounter "oracle" this term in multi-armed bandit literatures. But none of papers explain what that means. An example: [Practical Contextual Bandits with Regression Oracles](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.01088)

Comment: An *oracle* is something which knows the answer to the question asked, often in the context of an NP-hard problem.

Answer (score 3):

In the paper you mentioned the regression oracle

\begin{equation}
\operatorname{ORACLE}(H)=\underset{f \in \mathcal{F}}{\arg \min } \sum_{(w, x, a, y) \in H} w(f(x, a)-y)^{2}
\end{equation}

it's just an optimiser that starting from the data $H$ returns an optimal regressor.